# RoR: rendering multiple items for JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know I can't call `render` multiple times in a single action, but maybe someone can suggest an alternative to this for updating the contents of multiple DOM elements in an AJAX response.

I had in mind to do this:

```
render :json => {:updates => {'#a' => '<p>newContentA</p>', '#b' => '<p>newContentB</p>'}}
```

...then have the js on the front end carry out the substitutions (thereby keeping javascript out of my actual view files). But with the foregoing solution, if I want any DOM contents to be built from a view file, I would have to call render again:

```
render :json => {:updates => {'#a' => render(a), '#b' => '<p>newContentB</p>'}}
```

What's a proper way to execute this?

Comment: just render the whole thing and then use ids on the response to replace stuff in your view

Comment: Will that not entail wrapping the individual partials in javascript inside of a view file?